# Can i run an AC/DC adapter cable behind a wall?

Tags: electrical, wiring

**Edit 3: Verdict: It's possible to run the first part behind the wall because it's written "FT1" on the cable. Thanks A LOT to this community!**

I want to mount 2 monitors on a wall and hide the cables behind it... but I read online that you cannot run power cords behind walls. The thing is that it has 2 parts: a power cord and a separate power adapter (like in the photo).

I was wondering if it was safe to only run the cable connected to the monitor behind the wall... and then connect the "brick" adapter and the power cord outside the wall?

Thanks for your help!

**Edit 1: I'm from Canada. I bought the monitor at Best Buy Canada, but it looks like the cables were made in China.**

**Edit 2: I'm not sure what is the AC or DC part so I added more photos to answer your comments. Note that the last photo showing the power adapter is not the exact model that I have. I found it on Google but it looks the same. Again, thanks A LOT for your help it's very appreciated! :)**

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Hi @ccbk04 - what will you do if the adapter dies, or the cable becomes faulty ??  Power bricks are not known for their longevity ...

Comment: It is possible if there is no connection inside the wall. But I would use some channels.

Comment: Can you post the markings on the power adapter's DC cable please?

Comment: Where are you? I wonder because although I'm not an expert on NRTL marks I don't see a mark indicating US Listing.

Comment: @NoSparksPlease There are two UL Listing stamps, one for Canada with a file number, and another one for AR (??)  I also see two TUV listings.    EAC might be another NRTL.  Samsung is a perfectly competent company, but why they'd have anything built in *China* makes no sense when they *are a Korean company*.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica I didn't recognize either of the UL (Canada and Argentina) or either of the TUV marks as US accepted marks, making me wonder if maybe the question came from a locale with different rules. I wasn't implying non-US NRTL meant unsafe, just for some reason not submitted.

Comment: @NoSparkesPlease Yes I'm from Canada! I updated the post with more info I don't know if it can help you?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel I posted the markings on the cables in the post. Thanks!

Comment: To see if you can run the adapter's cable, please take a picture of the black wire on the right side in the last picture, clearly showing any (probably white) writing on it.

Comment: @P2000 It's not clear on the cable the writing is very small but here is what is written: E148000 ЯU AWM STYLE 1777 16AWG 80°C 300V VW-1 --- C ЯU AWM I/II A/B 80°C 300V FT1 -LF- PC10 LTE

Comment: FT1 is ok for inside the wall. I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 4):

Since your 22v would behind the wall yes this part could be run inside the wall and back out if the wire is listed.

I would get a recessed receptacle and mount the brick behind the monitor , or even a flush monitor and put the brick on the wall behind the monitor.

The only question would be is the wire rated for use inside the wall yes the cable would have to be listed for this, even speaker wire has to be listed to run it inside the walls I have been called several times on new DIY builds where a inspector failed a job because the large clear coated speaker wire was pulled for use in the walls.

There are plastic wire chases that stick to walls(wire mold being 1 brand) These have a snap on cover this would be another choice to consider that would be better than routing the cable in the wall.

Comment: yup.................+

Comment: yup...................+

Comment: Hi, thanks for your complete answer! I added more info in the post I don't know if you can tell if the wire is rated for use inside the wall?

Comment: @EdBeal Also I really want to hide the cable behind the wall and put the brick on the bottom of my desk so that it looks clean from the side. Do you think the way I arranged it on image #1 would be alright? Thanks a lot btw!!

Comment: Looking at the specs for AWM (appliance wiring material) it would meet many of the requirements of field wiring and it could be used in your appliances but it is not listed for field wiring. It is 300v rated and 1 specification stated low smoke by these are standards that field wiring requires. If the wire met the NEC requirements it could be argued it met the code intent, with that said your plan would look neat and be hidden you could use low voltage box eliminators like a WBF-1 and a blank cover plate with a hole drilled for the cable at the entrance and behind the monitor, the WBF-1 cost 1

Answer (score 1):

Based on the update in the question, the fire rating of the adapter's low voltage wire is "FT1", which is ok for inside the wall.

Just double check and confirm that the space you are running it in is not also a return duct for your heating system. If that's the case, you need FT4 cable.

If you wish to run a separate wire, you can use so called "Thermostat Wire" behind the wall, a.k.a. "LVT 18/5", and through return ducts. This wire is CSA FT4 rated (for Canada).

This is for the low voltage side of your adapter (adapter to monitor), not the line side (so not for adaptor to wall plug).

Poke a hole at the monitor and feed the wire down and out at a hole at the bottom. This wire is Fire Rated for use behind walls. Generally the wire that comes with the adapter cannot be used for this.

[image]

I like thermostat wire because you can buy it by the foot at hardware stores, it is rated for this purpose, and you can tie two colours together for a higher wire gauge ("thickness"), e.g. blue & black together for one lead of your adapter, and red & brown for the other lead. Whether the output is AC or DC does not matter. At 22V you are ok.

If you have questions about fishing the wire behind the wall, let us know.

Here's an overview of the required fire rating in different applications:

[image]

Source [here](https://www.markham.ca/wps/wcm/connect/markham/bae64a0e-3f8e-416d-af17-cf85a83c2ff5/Electrical+wires+and+cables.pdf?MOD=AJPERES&CONVERT_TO=url&CACHEID=ROOTWORKSPACE.Z18_2QD4H901OGV160QC8BLCRJ1001-bae64a0e-3f8e-416d-af17-cf85a83c2ff5-msjF1jI)